# Odoo 11 override name_get returns only SuperUsers id

Tags: odoo-11

I override res.company and create some new fields. And I wanted to show some different name for some groups users. And I override name_get in here. But self.env.uid always return only Superusers(Administrator) id. 
Have any idea?
Here is my sample code:

```
class ResCompanyCustom(models.Model):
  _inherit = "res.company"
  full_name = fields.Char(string='Company Full Name')
  @api.multi
  def name_get(self):
    result = []
    for record in self:
      user = self.env['res.users'].browse(self.env.uid)
      if user.has_group('manager'):
        result.append((record.id, record.full_name))
      else:
        result.append((record.id, record.name))
      return result
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess You have logged in as a superuser Because of that it return superuser id.

self.env.uid will return Id of Current Login User

self.env.user will return Current User Record

Comment: I logged both users. Admin and not admin users. But its returning only superusers id in both case.